# AngularJS ng-options not populating

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects that I bind to the scope. My view then accesses the objects via ng-options like this:

```
<div class="tile block box-shadow">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Reason for change</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.value as item.description for item in controller.priceChangeReasons" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

but the dropdown has nothing when you select it.
I have logged the priceChangeReasons and can see that the array is working and returning values.
I have made a codepen to show the issue:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/XbQzMa?editors=101

I realise this is probably a syntax error on my part, but I can't see it.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOptions` directive requires `ngModel`, just add:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.value as item.description for item in controller.priceChangeReasons" ng-model="controller.reason" />
```

and all should work